# Phrase Tree into Array

Tags: algorithm, tree, phrase

I have this phrase tree

> (ROOT
>     (S
>       (NP
>         (ADJP (JJ Bahasa)
>         (NN daerah) (NN merupakan) (NN bahasa) (NN yang) (NN digunakan) (NN dalam) (NN bahasa) (NN pergaulan) (NN sehari-hari) (NN di) (NN suatu) (NN daerah) (NNP tertentu))
>       (VP (VBZ .))))

I need to convert into array, like this

> S -> NP VP
> NP -> ADJP NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN
> ADJP -> JJ
> VP -> VBZ
> etc....

is there any algorithm to convert them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can practically see exactly what needs to be done.

every opening bracket is a child, every closing bracket is the end of children for that element.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but it's a simple as that...

read this for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree

Comment: yeah, solved, I try to loop it until the end of the tree, and get the relation.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Python code based on a library [pymeta2](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/pymeta) that parses this type of tree.

```
import pymeta.grammar

def f(name,E):
    print name+' -> '+' '.join(E)
    return name

G=pymeta.grammar.OMeta.makeGrammar("""
name = spaces ('.'|letterOrDigit|'-')+:n -> ''.join(n)
expr = token("(") name:p expr+:e token(")") -> f(p,e)
     | token("(") name:p name:e token(")") -> p
""",{'f':f})

s="(ROOT (S (NP (ADJP (JJ Bahasa)) (NN daerah) (NN merupakan) (NN bahasa) (NN yang) (NN digunakan) (NN dalam) (NN bahasa) (NN pergaulan) (NN sehari-hari) (NN di) (NN suatu) (NN daerah) (NNP tertentu)) (VP (VBZ .))))"

G(s).apply("expr")
```

The output of running this code is:

```
ADJP -> JJ
NP -> ADJP NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NN NNP
VP -> VBZ
S -> NP VP
ROOT -> S
```

(I had to add one extra bracket after (JJ Bahasa) to make this work.  I suspect this is a typo in the question?)

Comment: yeah, it's work, I already try it, but my problem is in php language.. but I read your algorithm and I solved my problem :).. thank you